# AngularJS Building JSON for Odata Call

Tags: angularjs, json, json.net, odata

We are currently having a drop down that has the ability to multi select

```
<select name="mM" class="form-control" ng-model="request.mM" multiple>
 <option ng-repeat="mM in mMs">{{ mM.value }}</option>
</select>
```

We are trying to retrieve the values selected and passing it in the Body of the OData Post Call, but generates as a array

Comment: If you do `console.log($scope.request.mM)`, what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an array of two string values. By using the `join` method and specifying the seperator, you can join the two values into one string:

```
var data = {
  "R_MMETHOD": $scope.request.mM.join(",")  // results in "abc,def"
};
```

This also works if there is only 1 value in the array